# Is there a site where I can ask question regarding electricity?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to know if there is any Stack Exchange website where I can ask questions regarding electricity (voltage, current, power calculation, sine wave graph pattern, etc.) since currently I have a few questions regarding electricity that I would like to ask and get confirmation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

The tour says:

> Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for **electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts**. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites.

So, you can ask your questions there. Don't forget to visit their [help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help), [on-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages before posting your questions.